# Ordering after childrencount in Child node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to order after the amount of childnodes a child has in firebase.

```
Query query = databaseChildRef.orderByChild("likes").limitToLast(10);
```

Likes are stored as an Long here so this one is being queried fine, but when I try to retrive a list of the child with the most comments (List)

```
Query query = databaseChildRef.orderByChild("comments").limitToLast(10);
```

...the same principle doesn't apply.

Is there a way to order after the count of child nodes in child "comment".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database does not support any server-side aggregation operators. If you want to order on the number of comments, you'll need to store a `commentCount` property and keep that up to date.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just made it more complex than it actually was.